# Как получить базовый тип переменной шаблона

Tags: c++

Как получить базовый тип от `const char x[23]`?

> Пример #1: const char* x = "none"; // базовый тип - char*
>
> Пример #2: const char x[23] = "none"; // базовый тип - char[23] ВАЖНО!
>
> Пример #3 wchar_t* wx = L"wnone"; // базовый тип - wchar_t*

В примере 2 и кроется самая большая проблема, это не просто массив с автоматическим выделенным размером, а массив с заранее явно указанным размером. Вариаций может быть сколь угодно, и все они будут выдавать различный по меркам спецификатора `decltype` тип данных, то есть `char[1], char[2], char[50] ...`. Отпределить такой тип данных будет невозможно, вернее возможно, если написать от 1 до 10000000 вариаций `is_same_v<T, char[...]>`.

Я искал в `cppref`, но ничего подобного не нашел, единственное полезное что я нашел это удаление `cv` квалификаторов и всё, но если квалификатор равен `const char*` , то эта песня уже не сыграет. Как можно получить "базовый тип" переменной массива или же указателя строки, который будет подобен `char*` / `char[]` ?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

template<typename T>
void test(T& v)
{
    if (std::is_same_v<T, char*>
        || std::is_same_v<T, char[]>)
    {
        std::cout << "string";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "isnt string";
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char* a = "";
    test(a); // string

    char b[] = "";
    test(b); // string

    const char* example1 = "example";
    test(example1); // isnt string

    const char example2[50] = "example2";
    test(example2); // isnt string
}
```

Comment: Вы точно уверены, что у вас второй случай печатает `"string"`? У меня нет.

Comment: `wchar_t* wx = L"wnone"` - некорректно без `const`. Сделайте более аккуратную постановку задачи.

Answer (score 1):

Это несложно:

```
#include <type_traits>
#include <cstddef>

template<typename T> class
my_trait;

template<typename T> class
my_trait<T *>
{
    public: using type = ::std::remove_cv_t<T> *;
};

template<typename T, ::std::size_t ItemsCount> class
my_trait<T[ItemsCount]>
{
    public: using type = ::std::remove_cv_t<T> [ItemsCount];
};

template<typename T> using
my_trait_t = typename my_trait<T>::type;

static_assert(::std::is_same_v<char *, my_trait_t<const char *>>);
static_assert(::std::is_same_v<char [23], my_trait_t<const char [23]>>);
static_assert(::std::is_same_v<wchar_t *, my_trait_t<wchar_t *>>);
```

Answer (score 1):

Думаю вам нужно это:

```
if ((std::is_pointer_v<T> && std::is_same_v<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_pointer_t<T>>, char>) ||
    (std::is_array_v<T> && std::is_same_v<std::remove_const_t<std::remove_extent_t<T>>, char>))
```

`remove_pointer_t` превращает `char *` в `char`, и т.д.

`remove_extent_t` превращает `char [N]` в `char`, и т.д.